# Android app crashes at setContentView(R.layout.XXXXXX);

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error, setcontentview

My app gets crashed after the execution of setContentView line. Here is my logcat

```
 --------- beginning of crash
05-09 14:46:29.664 12307-12307/com.bitproject.driverapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.bitproject.driverapplication, PID: 12307
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bitproject.driverapplication/com.bitproject.driverapplication.SettingsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.bitproject.driverapplication.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:37)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.bitproject.driverapplication.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:37) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.bitproject.driverapplication.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:37) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.bitproject.driverapplication:drawable/profile_image" (7f0700a1) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0700a1 a=-1 r=0x7f0700a1}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2602)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
        at de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.<init>(CircleImageView.java:98)
        at de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.<init>(CircleImageView.java:94)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.bitproject.driverapplication.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:37) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
05-09 14:46:29.892 12307-12375/com.bitproject.driverapplication V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 3084
05-09 14:46:29.897 12307-12375/com.bitproject.driverapplication V/FA: Activity paused, time: 64601668
```

I'm very new to android, I tried to read the log and find the issue. But I failed. There are a couple of related questions but can't understand how to relate them with mine.

Here's the Java file.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button updateAccountSettings;
    private EditText username;
    private CircleImageView userProfileImage;
    private String currentUserID;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference rootRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);               <----------------- App crashes at here

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Driver");

        updateAccountSettings =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_settings_button);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.set_user_name);
        userProfileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.set_profile_image);

        updateAccountSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateSettings();
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateSettings() {
        String setUsername = username.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(setUsername)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your user name...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            HashMap<String, String> profileMap = new HashMap<>();
            profileMap.put("UserID", currentUserID);
            profileMap.put("Name", setUsername);

            rootRef.child(currentUserID).setValue(profileMap)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MessageActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();

                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Profile Updates Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                String message = task.getException().toString();
                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error! " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

I have another activity called mainActivity. If there is no user name under currentUserId at firebase the mainActivity will have an intent to settingsActivity (java coding have provided above). When it gets intent the error occurs.

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/set_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_image"
        app:civ_border_width="5dp"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/set_user_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/set_profile_image"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:drawablePadding="20dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/edit_profile"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorSecondaryText"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/update_settings_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/set_user_name"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:text="Update"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/button_corner"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your XML has issue

Comment: Delete CircleImageView from your XML.

Comment: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.bitproject.driverapplication:drawable/profile_image" (7f0700a1) is not a Drawable (color or path).

Are you sure that profile_image is valid image? Could you post your activity_settings.xml file?

Comment: I have updated the XML file. The circleImageView have added with the dependency of `implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'`

Comment: Make sure your `profile_image` drawable is in your main `drawable` folder, not in `drawable-v21` or anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource
>   "com.bitproject.driverapplication:drawable/profile_image" (7f0700a1)
>   is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0700a1 a=-1
>   r=0x7f0700a1}

Check these lines at your logcat carefully. I ran your code in my environment. It just worked fine. There is no problem in inflating `CircleImageView`. It is clear that your `@drawable/profile_image` is not a valid drawable, may be it is not a supported image file or it is corrupted. Using a valid drawable will solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in **CircleImageView**. With deleting it your problem will be solved. Check its library to be correctly imported.

Comment: Can't I resolve the issue without deleting that? The dependency line has mentioned above as a comment. Can you please help me to fix this.